# Use blur function to setValue on Reactive Form the value change but display incorrectly

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am trying to add 0 in front of the value on a field in reactive form when blur is triggered

HTML

```
<input type="number" formControlName="toTiminghh" (blur)="onBlurTiming('toTiminghh')">
```

TS

```
onBlurTiming(formControlName) {
   if (this.voiceRatingForm.controls[formControlName].value != null) {
     if (this.voiceRatingForm.controls[formControlName].value.toString().length == 1) {
       this.voiceRatingForm.controls[formControlName].patchValue('0' + this.voiceRatingForm.controls[formControlName].value);
     }
   }
}
```

For example when I input 1 in the form the value is changed to 01 but still display 1 in the input.

Am I doing things correct?

**EDIT**

I found out why the value is not changing.It is because input type number tag in html does not allow leading 0 in value so the display is not change.

Comment: you have to convert to string

Comment: you should be using it as `(blur)="onBlurTiming(toTiminghh)"` enclosing it in single quotes `''` will send it as string

Comment: @Niladri Isn't it already string in the last line when I am patching the value? Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @Aravind not enclosing it with single quotes resulted in can't find the formControl.

Comment: if you want the number to display 01 when you enter 1, it should work as is. Please create a demo :)